# Pass selected element from list group Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf and Spring MVC for a project and I am displaying a list in Thymeleaf and I want to get the selected items and pass them when I press submit

This is my form with the list:

```
  <form th:action="@{/trip-info}" th:object="${trip}" method="post">
....
     <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" th:each="currentPerson : ${trip.employees}" th:text="${currentPerson.getFirstName() + ' ' + currentPerson.getLastName()}" onclick="addPerson(this)"></a>

</form>
```

I have the employees list displayed in my page, now I am not sure if I can pass to a controller the selected values or if I must use javascript and construct a body. Does anybody have any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Transferring the selected form item is outside the role of 'Thymeleaf'.
'Thymeleaf' is a server side template engine that simply creates code in html.
The event (item select) changed by the client must be processed by JavaScript.

For a simple example,
Before submitting from the form, check the selected item in javascript and create a function that performs the submit.

If you need an example, show me your source code in more detail.

- Additional comments -

There are two ways.
1. How does 'a tag' directly tell you about your event?
2. How to externally liseten events of 'a tag'

I wanted the '2' method, and you chose the '1' method.
Your source will be terminated with the href moved before executing the 'onclick' event.

Take a look at this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" onclick="someEvent(this)">some method</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" onclick="someEvent(this)">some method2</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" onclick="someEvent(this)">some method3</a><br/>

<script>
    function someEvent(event){
        console.log(event);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

'href' works but is invalidated by void (0). Or moved to another window tab by target. And then onclick happens sequentially.

I can not speak English and the explanation is immature. I'm sorry.

Comment: I am passing my object into the addPerson() function in the onclick event but it does not get passed